# Is it possible to have my Company to be assigned to IP address

Tags: whois

I have no idea how IP allocation works, but I rented VPS from one provider along with 5 IP addresses, now this provider hosts servers at Dimenoc.

When I see `whois` record for my IP address,  I see Dimehost's information there. Is it possible for me to have my own company address assigned there?

Comment: It's a lot of work, and pretty pointless. I wouldn't expect a VPS provider to allow it, either.

Comment: @ceejayoz I wouldn't say it's pointless - if something's wrong (spamming, compromised server, etc) I prefer people to contact me directly so I can act quickly rather then waiting for my ISP to forward me the email.

Answer (score 6):

IP allocation is layered, with the Regional Internet Registry (RIR) for your geographic region controlling all IPs; these are then assigned to Local Internet Registries (LIRs) in large netblocks (typically /16 or bigger), who sell them to ISPs and - sometimes - individuals or corporations.

Your first point of contact will be your ISP, but if you expect to change ISP in the future you may want to request a netblock from the LIR governing your area; however, single IPs are not often distrubted by the LIR (if at all).

Answer (score 5):

Some providers offer SWIP capabilities which will let you add your whois details to the Whois record. This however requires a minimum 8 IP block.

https://www.arin.net/resources/request/reassignments.html

You may want to see if you obtain a 8 IP block if they will provide SWIP'd Whois.   You will still see a referral to your provider's whois servers but the record listing will show your data.